# Integration of three dimensional function gives wrong answer!

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I have the following integration

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d^{3}\mathbf{p}\nabla\cdot\frac{\mathbf{p}}{(p_{x}^{2}+p_{y}^{2}+p_{z}^{2}+m^{2})^{3/2}}$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d^{3}\mathbf{p}\left(\partial_{x}\frac{p_{x}}{(p_{x}^{2}+p_{y}^{2}+p_{z}^{2}+m^{2})^{3/2}}\right.\\\partial_{y}\frac{p_{x}}{(p_{x}^{2}+p_{y}^{2}+p_{z}^{2}+m^{2})^{3/2}}\\\left.\partial_{z}\frac{p_{x}}{(p_{x}^{2}+p_{y}^{2}+p_{z}^{2}+m^{2})^{3/2}}\right)$$

When I put the first part into Mathematica, I found:

```
 Assuming[m^2 > 0, 
 Integrate[D[px (px^2 + py^2 + pz^2 + m^2)^(-3/2), px], 
   {px, -∞, +∞}, {py, -∞, +∞}, {pz, -∞, +∞}]]
```

result: $4\pi$.

However, if I put all the three terms:

```
Assuming[m^2 > 0, 
Integrate[
  D[px (px^2 + py^2 + pz^2 + m^2)^(-3/2), px] + 
  D[py (px^2 + py^2 + pz^2 + m^2)^(-3/2), py] + 
  D[pz (px^2 + py^2 + pz^2 + m^2)^(-3/2), pz], 
  {px, -∞, +∞}, {py, -∞, +∞}, {pz, -∞, +∞}]]
```

the result is also $4\pi$. This is very strange. Should it be $12\pi$?

---

#### Update

In other words, why should the integral depend on the order of the integration variables?

$$\int dp_{x}dp_{y}dp_{z}\left[\frac{1}{(p_{x}^{2}+p_{y}^{2}+p_{z}^{2}+m^{2})^{3/2}}-\frac{3p_{x}^{2}}{(p_{x}^{2}+p_{y}^{2}+p_{z}^{2}+m^{2})^{5/2}}\right]=4\pi$$
$$\neq\int dp_{y}dp_{z}dp_{x}\left[\frac{1}{(p_{x}^{2}+p_{y}^{2}+p_{z}^{2}+m^{2})^{3/2}}-\frac{3p_{x}^{2}}{(p_{x}^{2}+p_{y}^{2}+p_{z}^{2}+m^{2})^{5/2}}\right]=0$$

#

By the way, if I use `Nintegrate` the order does not affect the result, very strange!!

```
m=1.;   
NIntegrate[
     D[px (px^2 + py^2 + pz^2 + m^2)^(-3/2), 
      px], {px, -\[Infinity], +\[Infinity]}, {py, -\[Infinity], +\
    \[Infinity]}, {pz, -\[Infinity], +\[Infinity]}]
```

result: 12.5565.

```
NIntegrate[
 D[px (px^2 + py^2 + pz^2 + m^2)^(-3/2), 
  px], {py, -\[Infinity], +\[Infinity]}, {pz, -\[Infinity], +\
\[Infinity]}, {px, -\[Infinity], +\[Infinity]}]
```

result: 12.5565.

Very strange!!! And this is very dangerous for the numerical calculation.

Comment: Did you set a value for `m` in `NIntegrate`? I get the same result setting `m=1`.  The numerical value is 4 Pi.

Comment: @mikado Yes, m=1. And the order of integration variables now does not affect the result.

Comment: I think Fubini–Tonelli does not apply. It’s similar to the last counterexample here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem

Comment: "Very strange!!! And this is very dangerous for the numerical calculation." -- **1.** `NIntegrate` does not use iterative integration. **2.** It is assumed that the Fubini-Tonelli theorem applies to most of the integrals given to `NIntegrate`. **3.** For the integrals in the question you are most likely going to get different results using Cartesian rules.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The integral over the subregion does not converge:

```
Integrate[
 (m^2 - 2 x^2 + y^2 + z^2)/(m^2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(5/2),
 {y, -Infinity, Infinity},
 {z, -Infinity, Infinity},
 {x, -Sqrt[1 + y^2 + z^2], Sqrt[1 + y^2 + z^2]}, 
 Assumptions -> m > 0 && {x, y, z} \[Element] Reals]
(*  Infinity  *)
```

The triple integral does not equal the iterated integral, something that `Integrate[]` misses.

The surface `m^2 - 2 x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 0` divides space into a region over which the integral diverges to positive infinity and one over which the integral diverges to negative infinity.
One could try to choose a principal value.  One has to be aware that one can obtain any result.  The surface `m^2 - 2 x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 0` was a convenient (and somewhat obvious) choice for analyzing the divergence of the integral.  It is not necessarily for it to be used to define a principal value. A common choice is as follows.  It has the appealing attraction of corresponding somewhat with the symmetry of the integral.  Since over a ball $B$ centered at the origin we have by symmetry
$$\textstyle
\int_B \frac{x^2}{\left(m^2+x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{5/2}} \; dV
 = \int_B \frac{y^2}{\left(m^2+x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{5/2}} \; dV
 = \int_B \frac{z^2}{\left(m^2+x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{5/2}} \; dV \,,
$$
therefore we get some cancellation and
$$
\int_B \frac{m^2-2 x^2+y^2+z^2}{\left(m^2+x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{5/2}} \; dV
 = \int_B \frac{m^2}{\left(m^2+x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{5/2}} \; dV
 = \frac{4 \pi  R^3}{3 \left(m^2+R^2\right)^{3/2}}
$$
which converges to $4\pi/3$ as the radius $R$ goes to infinity.

But maybe its attraction is as a Siren leading sailors into a shipwreck.

Comment: The integration limits you specify for `z` will be imaginary for some values of `x` and `y`.  I don't know if this matters.

Answer (score 5):

The integral is indeed equal to
$$
\iiint (f_x+f_y+f_z)=4\pi
$$
where $f_i=\partial_i(p_i/(p^2+m^2)^{3/2})$. This is easy to prove using spherical symmetry and e.g. the Gauss theorem (the integral is basically the residue at infinity, and so independent of $m$).

**The integral is perfectly convergent**; indeed, it is easy to see that $(f_x+f_y+f_z)\sim 1/r^5$:

```
Div[{px, py, pz}/(px^2 + py^2 + pz^2 + m^2)^(3/2), {px, py, pz}] /. {px -> r Cos[θ] Sin[ϕ], py -> r Cos[θ] Cos[ϕ], pz -> r Sin[θ]} // FullSimplify
Series[%, {r, ∞, 4}]
(* O[1/r]^5 *)
```

The **problem** is that the partial integrals
$$
\iiint f_i
$$
**do not exist individually**. Indeed, they are $f_i\sim 1/r^3$:

```
D[px/(px^2 + py^2 + pz^2 + m^2)^(3/2), px] /. {px -> r Cos[θ] Sin[ϕ], py -> r Cos[θ] Cos[ϕ], pz -> r Sin[θ]} // FullSimplify
Series[%, {r, ∞, 2}]
(* O[1/r]^3 *)
```

(This, together with $\mathrm d\boldsymbol p=4\pi p^2\mathrm dp$ means that the integrand is $\sim 1/r$, which is not integrable).

Unfortunately, Mathematica **was not able to identify the divergence of the integral: the result it yields is just meaningless**.

Comment: So Fubinis theorem does not apply here? Interesting.

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be a case where you genuinely cannot change the order of integration.  I think it's a Mathematics problem not a Mathematica problem.

Define relevant assumptions

```
$Assumptions = {px^2 > 0, py^2 > 0, pz^2 > 0};
```

Evaluate and simplify the integrand

```
expr = 
 D[px (px^2 + py^2 + pz^2 + m^2)^(-3/2), px] /. m -> 1 // FullSimplify
(* (1 - 2 px^2 + py^2 + pz^2)/(1 + px^2 + py^2 + pz^2)^(5/2) *)
```

The integral w.r.t. `px` is zero.  (This can be verified easily by specifying numerical values for `py` and `pz`)

```
Integrate[expr, {px, -∞, ∞}]
(* 0 *)
```

Integrating w.r.t. `py` and `pz`

```
Integrate[expr, {py, -∞, ∞}, {pz, -∞, ∞}]
(* (2 π)/(1 + px^2)^(3/2) *)
```

Since the integrand is always positive, this is unsurprisingly non-zero

```
Integrate[%, {px, -∞, ∞}]
(* 4 π *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer, but we can see Mathematica returns a different answer, depending on the order in which the integration is performed.

```
Assuming[m^2 > 0, 
 Integrate[
  D[px (px^2 + py^2 + pz^2 + m^2)^(-3/2), 
   px], {px, -∞, +∞}, {py, -∞, +∞}, {pz, -∞, +∞}]]
(* 4 π *)

Assuming[m^2 > 0, 
 Integrate[
  D[px (px^2 + py^2 + pz^2 + m^2)^(-3/2), 
   px], {pz, -∞, +∞}, {px, -∞, +∞}, {py, -∞, +∞}]]
(* 0 *)
```

Comment: why is the order of this integration matters? This is a very smooth function since m**2>0. I don't see any reasons why I can't change the order.