# Does Mathematica assume that the order of numerical integration can be changed?

Tags: numerical-integration

[This question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/209740/integration-of-three-dimensional-function-gives-wrong-answer) gives a 3-dimensional infinite integral where the correct  result (I believe) depends on the order in which the variables are specified.

Specifically

```
integrand = (1 - 2 x^2 + y^2 + z^2)/(1 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(5/2);

Assuming[x^2 > 0 && y^2 > 0 && z^2 > 0, 
 Integrate[integrand, {x, -∞, ∞}, {y, -∞, ∞}, {z, -∞, ∞}]]
(* 4 π *)

Assuming[x^2 > 0 && y^2 > 0 && z^2 > 0, 
 Integrate[integrand, {z, -∞, ∞}, {y, -∞, ∞}, {x, -∞, ∞}]]
(* 0 *)
```

Interestingly, with `NIntegrate` the two integrands give the same answer, but both warn of slow convergence.

```
Assuming[x^2 > 0 && y^2 > 0 && z^2 > 0, 
 NIntegrate[integrand, {x, -∞, ∞}, {y, -∞, ∞}, {z, -∞, ∞}]]
(* 12.5565 *)

Assuming[x^2 > 0 && y^2 > 0 && z^2 > 0, 
 NIntegrate[integrand, {z, -∞, ∞}, {y, -∞, ∞}, {x, -∞, ∞}]]
(* 12.5565*)
```

Comment: For comparison, what happens when you switch to spherical coordinates?

Comment: @J.M.willbebacksoon analytically, integrating one dimension at a time, it is quite easy to verify that `Integrate` is behaving correctly.  I've not tried spherical coordinates numerically.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

integrand = (1 - 2 x^2 + y^2 + z^2)/(1 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(5/2);

int[r_] = Assuming[r > 0, Integrate[
   integrand, {x, y, z} ∈ Ball[{0, 0, 0}, r]]]

(* (4 π r^3)/(3 (1 + r^2)^(3/2)) *)

Limit[int[r], r -> Infinity]

(* (4 π)/3 *)
```

Comment: Interesting.  I think that this confirms that the triple integral is not well defined, because its limiting value depends on the order in which the limits are taken (e.g. `x` first, `y` and `z` first or `r`)